# choosing a good representative genome subset

Tags: sequence-alignment, clustering, subset

I'm trying to build a genomic database for DNA alignments.
I started with NCBI accessions, but the data is very multiplicative, so I want to use subset of [max] N different strains for each specie.
my question is: I can i obtain the minimal N that the samples will be diverse enough and will cover the specie good?

Comment: Depends on what you are looking at (species) and secondly what post-alignment analysis you are planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the progenomes database: http://progenomes.embl.de/